# unit ball in $\mathbb C_p$ as an inverse limit

Tags: general-topology, ring-theory, nonarchimedian-analysis

I'm reading Robert's "A Course in $p$-adic Analysis". The Theorem at the bottom of page 79 says that there is an isomorphism $A \cong \varprojlim A/\xi^nA$. ($A$ is the unit ball and $\xi$ is an element with $\vert \xi \vert < 1$.)

[Robert p. 79](https://books.google.de/books?id=cDXoBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA79&lpg=PA79&dq=ultrametric%20field%20the%20representation%20theorem%20robert%20course&source=bl&ots=fDwzz1oAdt&sig=ACfU3U2G21pjYywNMTeaq0PVQZSLyjRjmg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwikp4Kk1d_iAhXMyKQKHW2nAm4Q6AEwAHoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=ultrametric%20field%20the%20representation%20theorem%20robert%20course&f=false)

Is the mentioned isomorphism an isomorphism of rings or of topological rings? What is the "correct" topology on $A/\xi^nA$?

Comment: $A = \{ x \in \Bbb{C}_p,|x| \le 1\}$ and $|.|$ induces a metric on $A/\xi^n A$ and $\varprojlim A/\xi^n A$, on the latter it is the same absolute value

Comment: now I get it, thanks!